# using indexOf to compare first and next element of array. JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, indexof

I'm going through Murach's JavaScript & JQuery book. I'm trying to create a lottery generator. Im currently stuck on how to use indexOf to compare the first element of the array to the next to make sure I don't get duplicates. My thought process is to do the printing of 5 random numbers while the number before it is not the same.

```
var numOfTickets;
do{
   numOfTickets = prompt("Enter number of lotto tickets (1-10)"); 
   numOfTickets = parseInt(numOfTickets);

   var lottoNum = new Array(5);
   do{
      for(var i = 0; i <lottoNum.length; i++){
      var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 47);
      lottoNum[i] = num;
   }
   document.write(lottoNum);
   }while(lottoNum.indexOf(i) != i+1)); //while the value of first index != to the next?


}
while(numOfTickets <1 || numOfTickets >10 ); //repeat prompt until valid.
```

Comment: `while(lottoNum[i] != lottoNum[i+1]));` ;)

Comment: That did not work but thanks. I thought i could do
`lottoNum[i] != lottoNum[i-1]` so that the current position in the array is compared to the previous but that didn't replace anything either. I'm still getting duplicates.

Comment: haha.. Right... While the loop is going, `i+1` just do not exist yet! So that should be `while(lottoNum[i] != lottoNum[i-1]));` !! Compare with the previous!! I answered quite too fast, sorry ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
var numOfTickets;
do {
    numOfTickets = prompt("Enter number of lotto tickets (1-10)");
    numOfTickets = parseInt(numOfTickets);
    var lottoNum = new Array(5);

    for (var i = 0; i < lottoNum.length; i++) {
        var num;

        do {
            num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 47);
        } while (lottoNum.indexOf(num) > -1);

        lottoNum[i] = num;
    }
    document.write(lottoNum);
}
while (numOfTickets < 1 || numOfTickets > 10); //repeat prompt until valid.
```

Comment: Here, the comparison is made, not only on the previous or next, but on all other values in the array... Good! I upvoted.

Comment: cause he uses i out of for loop,,,that always make mistakes,so i show the way of using indexOf

Comment: I just want to make i have the logic down. It stores the random number inside of num, while the first index is greater than -1 meaning indices from 0-5 and then you store the random number inside of the index it's currently at. With this code you aren't checking if there is duplicates though, correct? You're simply preventing them from happening?

Comment: lottoNum.indexOf(num) > -1  means that num in the lottoNum,so get the random num again until the next num not in the lottoNum. when the num not in the lottoNum, lottoNum.indexOf(num) returns -1;actually,if num in the lottoNum,lottoNum.indexOf(num) returns >=0.So,always,we use that to compare with -1 not using like lottoNum.indexOf(num) !== -1 cause we don't know if one day it becomes -2 or other numbers.i am simply preventing duplicates  from happening.

Comment: It is kind of inefficient, better to pick a random item from an array of numbr (1 to 47) remove that item and then pick another random number from that array. If you want to pick as many numbers as there are in the array your code will pick many random numbers that are already picked near the end.

Comment: @HMR that's true, actually that's another logic

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code snippet to achieve what you need. Please read through the comments to get more clear on what has been done.

```js
numOfTickets = prompt("Enter number of lotto tickets (1-10)"); 
numOfTickets = parseInt(numOfTickets);

for(var i=0; i<numOfTickets; i++){
//specify how much number you need in each lotto
var lottoLength = 5; 
//initialize each lotto to empty
var lotto = [];
//loop over the lotto length
for(var j = 0; j <lottoLength; j++){
  //get your first random lotto number
  var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 47);
  //make sure that the lotto number do not match the number before it
  while(lotto.includes(num)){
    num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 47);
  }
  //push the number in the lotto
  lotto.push(num);
}
 //your final numOfTickets
  console.log(lotto);
}
```

This code will always ensure that the lotto number do not match with the number before it.

Answer (score 0):

**indexOf** is used to find the index at which a given element can be found in the array.

What you want to do is **access** the element at a particular index in the array.

You can do that by using bracket notation like this:

```
lottoNum[i] != lottoNum[i+1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pick from an array of numbers and remove that item from the array then call itself until you have the right amount of numbers:

```js
const getLottoNums = fromWhat => howMany => {
  const recur = (fromWhat, lottoNumbers ) => {
    if(lottoNumbers.length===howMany){
      //have the right amount of numbers, return it
      return lottoNumbers;
    }
    //you can never pick a number that's already been picked before because
    //  before calling recur again that number is removed from the "fromWhat" array
    const pickedNumber = fromWhat[Math.floor(Math.random() * fromWhat.length)];
    //recursively call itself removing the picked number from "fromWhat"
    return recur(//call itself again until we have enough numbers
      fromWhat.filter(x=>x!==pickedNumber),//filter out picked number
      lottoNumbers.concat([pickedNumber])//add picked number to lottoNmbers
    );
  }
  return recur(fromWhat,[]);
};

const getFrom47LottoNumbers = 
  getLottoNums(Array.from(new Array(47),(_,index)=>index+1));
document.body.addEventListener(
  "click",
  _=>console.log(getFrom47LottoNumbers(5))
);
```

```html
click here
```